# Duda tabla intermedia Hibernate ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy iniciandome en Hibernate y tengo un problemilla que no soy capaz de resolver.
Digamos que tengo dos entidades relacionadas ManyToMany. En la tabla intermedia que crea hibernate necesito añadir un campo mas aparte de las 2 primary keys de ambas tablas, esto no soy capaz de conseguirlo de ninguna manera, incluso en algunos sitios leo que es imposible hacerlo...

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Qué significaría ese campo?

Comment: Digamos que necesito una columna mas en una tabla intermedia, por ejemplo: Las entidades "Usuario" y "Bar" del cual la relación es muchos a muchos. Necesito una columna intermedia para almacenar el rol de dicho usuario en dicho bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es imposible, no.

Tienes que crear una entidad intermedia que representará la tabla en la que, en tu modelo físico, aplanarás esa relación M:N y en la que tendrás los atributos específicos de esa relación y convertirás la M:N en dos 1:N.

Este es un ejemplo mío: tengo una relación M:N entre la entidad SeriesEdition y la entidad EventSession. El detalle está en que para dada una instancia de campeonato (SeriesEdition), una de sesión (EventSession) y una de sistema de puntuación (PointsSystem), necesito guardar qué multiplicador de puntos hay que aplicar en ese caso (columna `ps_multiplier`)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POINTS_SYSTEM_SESSION")
public class PointsSystemSession {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PointsSystemSessionPK id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("series_edition_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERIES_EDITION_ID")
    private SeriesEdition seriesEdition;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("session_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "SESSION_ID")
    private EventSession eventSession;

    @ManyToOne
    private PointsSystem pointsSystem;

    @Column(name="ps_multiplier")
    private Float psMultiplier = 1.0f;

...
}
```

Y por si acaso, aunque no necesariamente te ha de hacer falta, esta es la tabla que define la clave de la entidad:

```
@Embeddable
public class PointsSystemSessionPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5431412749175457078L;

    @Column(name = "SESSION_ID")
    private Long sessionId;

    @Column(name = "SERIES_EDITION_ID")
    private Long seriesEditionId;

    public PointsSystemSessionPK() {
        super();
    }

    public PointsSystemSessionPK(Long sessionId, Long seriesEditionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
        this.seriesEditionId = seriesEditionId;
    }

...
}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad

Comment: Me he tirado dos dias para pillar tu ejemplo, una vez pillado a las mil maravillas. Millon de gracias!!!